# Most efficient way of extracting values from an array and passing to an ajax Post call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Currently I am calling ajax and posting the following object as data:

```
var answer = {
                checklist: {id: 1},
                question: {id: questionId },
                answer: "testing1",
                notes: checkInNotes
        };
```

On the server side, this updates the answer and notes in the database where a question and checklist with the id of 1 are found.

Now say I have an array of questionId's that I need to pass in to ajax as part of that question property in that object above. What would be the best way to achieve this in ajax?

Currently I can achieve this by sending an ajax call off to the server x amount of times for each value that I need updated in the database, but this is obviously inefficient.

I'm quite new to ajax so please forgive my lack of knowledge.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: `ids: questionIds.join(",")` or add as array and handle on server

Answer (score 0):

JSON allows arrays as well as objects.

You can include an array as one of your object properties (if that is what you need) and get it in the server.

```
var answer = {
                checklist: {id: 1},
                question: {id: questionId },
                answer: "testing1",
                notes: checkInNotes,
                arrayOfQuestionId: [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
        };
```

You could also send an array of objects instead of just one:

```
var otherAnswer = [ object1, object2, ... ];
```

Answer (score 0):

tips: generate mix data and post all it to sever side.

> 1.send all requests from client
>    2.send all mix data to server and be parsed.

way1: **from server**

```
let url='*',ids=[1,2,3];
```

//generate paramse of array.

```
function getarams(){
 let requests_params=ids.map(i=>{
    let data_temp={question:{id:i}}
    return data_temp;
  }||[];
 return resuests_params;
}
```

//be parsed from server

```
$.post(url,{data:getParams()},function(data,status){},'json');<br>
```

way2: send all posts once

```
let posts=getParams().map(d=>{
       return $.post(url,d)
});
$.when(posts[0],posts[1],posts[2]).then(result=>{
   console.log(result);
})
```